# Find height of a square pyramid given only its base width and lateral face angle

Tags: geometry

I'm not sure how to even begin, so I'm throwing this out for the experts.

Let's say I have a typical square pyramid with a base 100x100 meters.

And, the only other thing I know is the lateral face angle, which is the angle formed between two neighboring side faces of the pyramid.

Given only these two measurements of the pyramid, how would I figure out its height?

(For an explanation of the the lateral face angle,  see here :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rvVmp-v_D6E.)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Let $a$ be the side length of the base square and $\theta$ the lateral face angle. Also, let $\beta$ be the angle between the pyramid’s height and side edges. From the right triangles in the diagram, we have

$$\tan\frac{\theta}{2}  = \frac{1}{\cos\beta} = \frac{b}{OP}\tag{1}$$

where $b$ is half of diameter length of the base square, i.e. $b=a/\sqrt 2$. The height of the pyramid $h$ is,

$$ h = \frac{b}{\tan\beta} $$

From (1),

$$\tan\beta = \sqrt{ \tan^2\frac{\theta}{2} -1}$$

Thus, the height is

$$h= \frac{a}{\sqrt{ 2\left(\tan^2\frac{\theta}{2} -1\right)}}$$

Answer (score 0):

*Hint.* Take a midsection with a vertical plane passing through the vertex and the centre of the base. Then you have an isosceles triangle, whose base and vertex angle you know. You can then find its altitude easily.

Comment: The OP does not know the angle between the base and a side face, but only the angle between two side faces.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I didn't talk about base angles, but a *base.*

Comment: Regardless, you claim that in the triangle there is a known angle. There isn't. The apex angle is the angle between two non-adjacent side faces. The OP only knows the angle at an edge between adjacent side faces.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I see OP has edited this recently. When I answered I seem to recall that I read something else.